Elisp: 'Symbol's value as variable is void' when evaluating a function
When evaluating the following function, I get "Symbol's value as variable is void: s"
(defun str-to-sym () (interactive)
      (sx (kill-sexp 1)
      (let ((s (read (car kill-ring))))
    (insert (downcase (reps s " " "-"))))
    ))


sx is an alias for save-excursion.
Evaluating the following
    (let ((s (read (car kill-ring))))
       (message "!!: %s" s))
 
   => !!: quote''

but evaluating what is essentially the same construct, I think, outside of the function str-to-sym works.
What's going on??
Just to clarify?? reps is a macro:
(defmacro reps (*s old &optional new limit)
  (let ((buf (make-buffer "*reps*" (eval *s))))
    (sx (set-buffer buf)
    (while (rep old new limit))
    (prog1 (buffer-string) (kill-buffer buf))))
  )

This is code I inherited, I believe it has worked in previous versions of Emacs.

.. and reps is an alias for replace-string? When you post a question, please don't use personal aliases. Also, when you say "When evaluating the following function ...", do you mean evaluating the defun or evaluating a call to the function? I presume the latter but in that case you will need to provide context: what is the s-expression that is killed in the first step?

Point taken ref 'sx'. This occurs when evaluating the defun.

There is no error when I evaluate (C-x C-e) the defun. Are you sure what you show above is what you tried to evaluate?

... and now rep is undefined. Is that another macro?

What is the specification of str-to-sym? If we knew what it is supposed to do, maybe we could come up with a version that does not suffer from the problems of the current code.

Good question - I've inherited this code, I know what the code as a whole is trying to achieve, but comments  and docstrings are lacking, so I'm trying to get to a point where I can start running and debugging to help me get to grips with it.
My Elisp knowledge is limited but hopefully growing.

Yes, just copied back into emacs and did C-x C-e, and get the same error.

I can't reproduce it: I paste the defun into my *scratch* buffer, do C-x C-e (or C-j). It's only when I call it that I get errors: (void-function sx), so I replace that with save-excursion and re-evaluate the defun, then calling it again gives me (void-function reps); so I add the macro and evaluate the defmacro which gives me an error (void-function make-buffer) which makes me wonder if the body of the macro should be (quasi-)quoted, but even then at runtime you are going to get the same error. In short, there is too much stuff that is wrong here and trying to fix one ...

... problem will just lead us into deeper doodoo. At the very least, you need to supply in your question all the pieces that are needed to be able to compile and run without running into void-function errors.

OK thanks for your help - looks as though I'll have to start reading the code and and drilling down macro/function by macro or function to get it to work, and rewriting it better rather than debugging something that runs (in some fashion). I was hoping that there was something obvious in the fragment that I provided.
